# How to use array of pointers to print structure entities?

Tags: c

I wrote a program in C which has a structure named `ak`. 
There is an array of pointers `s` which stores the address of array `p` of ak type. After inputting the values, only `str` is getting printed.

How can I print both `str` and `id` using array of pointers?

set 1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
    char str[10];
    int id;
}ak;

int main()
{   
    printf("Hey\n"); 
    int i;
    ak *s[5],p[5];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        s[i]=&p[i];
        printf("Input string:");
        scanf("%s",&p[i].str);
        printf("Input id:");
        scanf("%d",&p[i].id);
    }    
    i=0;
    while(i<5)
    {
        printf("%s\n",s[i].id);
        ++i;
    } 
    return 0;   
}
```

set 2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
    char str[10];
    int id;
}ak;

int main()
{  
    printf("Hey\n"); 
    int i;
    ak *s[5],p[5];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
         s[i]=&p[i];
         printf("Input string:");
         scanf("%s",&p[i].str);
         printf("Input id:");
         scanf("%d",&p[i].id);
    }    
    i=0;
    while(i<5)
    {
         printf("%s\n",s[i]);
         ++i;
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

So when I tried set1 code,it gave me error saying:

```
C:\CPP\c\Prototypes>gcc -o ct structure.c
structure.c: In function 'main':
structure.c:22:32: error: request for member 'id' in something not a structure or union

       printf("%s\n",*s[i].id);
                          ^
```

Screenshot is here:

https://imageshack.com/a/img921/3084/j1rHig.png

When I tried set2 code, it only printed str values.
screenshot is here:

https://imageshack.com/a/img922/614/JHSGZ9.png

Comment: The error message means you’re using the dot operator where you should be using the arrow operator, or vice versa.

Comment: Please use Copy&Paste to show us the text error messages. They are no artwork and don't need to be shown as images.

Comment: the `set1` does not compile.  How are we to advise you on run-time logic when you do not post code that compiles?

Comment: the `set2` results in the compiler giving two (serious) warnings: `untitled.c:17:18: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[10]’ [-Wformat=]` and `untitled.c:24:19: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘ak * {aka struct <anonymous> *}’ [-Wformat=]`  Both of these problems need to be corrected, or the code will not act as desired when run

Comment: OT: the struct definition is missing a 'tag' name.  Without a 'tag' name, most debuggers will not display the individual fields in the struct.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf("%s",&p[i].str);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]'  always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the end of the input.  This also assures that the buffer cannot be overrun with the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s",&p[i].str);`  the field `str[]` is an array  referencing an array results in the address of the first byte of the array, so this statement should be: `scanf("%9s",p[i].str);` similar considerations need to be applied to all the calls to `scanf()`

Comment: regarding: `printf("%s\n",s[i]);  this is trying to pass the whole struct instance to a '%s' output format specifier.  This will not work.  Suggest: `printf("%s\n",s[i]->str);

Answer (score 2):

Concerning set1 and your problems with `printf("%s\n",*s[i].id);`.

`*s[i].id` is equivalent to `*(s[i].id)`, not to `(*s[i]).id` as you probably supposed. Because the type of `s[i]` is `ak *` you cannot get its field *id* through `s[i].id`.

You can write `(*s[i]).id` but a more readable way is to use `s[i]->id`.

Your *printf* has an other problem, the format cannot be `"%s"` because `s[i]->id` is an *int*, not a *char **

---

Concerning set2

You do `printf("%s\n",s[i]);`, and you are surprised because only the string is printed, how can you expect that print the string *and* the int ?

You request to print a string (format `%s`) but `s[i]` is not a string. By *chance* the *struct* starts by the field *str* being a string, so yes you write it, but this is not the right way.

You have to explicitly print each attributes, for instance doing `printf("%s %d\n",s[i]->str, s[i]->id);`

Comment: @AthulKrishnan do you understand the problems ?